# How to destructure an array to POSTGRES parameter?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I want to know how to destructure an array variable in TypeORM or POSTGRESQL raw query.

I have the following query:

```
getConnection()
        .query(`SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3, t.col1, c.col1
                FROM schema.msomething m
                LEFT JOIN schema.csomething c ON m.col1 = c.col1
                LEFT JOIN schema.tsomething t ON m.col1 = t.col1
                WHERE ((m.start_date, m.end_date) OVERLAPS ($1, $2))
                AND (c.col1 IN ('valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC'))`,
                [
                    start_date,
                    end_date
                ]
        );
```

This query works fine as expected, but i want the `('valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC')` to become dynamic value assigned to `$3` which will be an **Array**,

I've tried following:

```
AND (c.col1 IN (...$3))
```

or

```
AND (c.col1 IN $3)
```

... but neither one works work at all.

Comment: You should be able to use named placeholders and say `c.col1 in (:...vals)` and `{ vals: ['valueA', 'valueB', 'valueC'] }` (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1239#issuecomment-366955628) rather than PostgreSQL-style numbered placeholders.

Comment: i need to use raw query since i use `OVERLAPS` here, the use of `:var` doesn't work in `.query()`

Comment: But wouldn't `where('... overlaps (:start, :end)', { start: start_date, end: end_date })` work in that case? I don't think the ORM really understands SQL, it is probably just doing some string wrangling combined with type checking and escaping. Otherwise you'd have to build the right number of numbered placeholders and then splat the array to provide values for those placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but i'd do it like this:

```
...
`c.col1 = ANY(string_to_array($3,$4))`,
[
  start, end,
  [1,2,3].join(SEP), SEP
]
...
```

Ofc you have to be sure, that your the `SEP` string is not in any items of your [1,2,3] array.